# Возможно ли установить recaptcha от google на систему не на PHP?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, ruby

Здравствуйте, есть сайт с закрытой CMS на ruby, возможно ли настроить каптчу без обработки на стороне сервера, что бы валидация проходила на AJAX, например?

Comment: В каком виде вам доступна эта CMS? Если она доступна как Rack handler, то способ, теоретически, есть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам тогда придется светить секретный ключ в коде javascript, что сводит смысл затеи примерно к нулю.